# ActivityMainBinding unresolved and Synch Error

Tags: android, kotlin, binding

I have added this line to `build.gradle` (Module app)

```
buildFeatures {
        dataBinding =true
    }
```

When I sync this error appears:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method buildFeatures() for arguments [build_19pjanuvhj80p00suq43vf27v$_run_closure1$_closure5@1bdce120] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.
```

`build.gradle` (Module app)

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.foodapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

I want to fix this error because I wanna make this line of code work because ActivityMainBinding shows as `unresolved reference`

lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
setContentView(binding.root)

This is the [image of the erro][1]r on the Activity.

Comment: Upload your build.gradle file

Comment: Show us the entire Gradle file to see where you have put the `buildFeatures {} Block`. You can edit your question and copy-paste the Gradle File code here or take a snapshot image of the Gradle File Code.

Comment: ok i update the question

Comment: hello please help me i really need help